# How big is too big size for table in AWS Redshift

Tags: database, amazon-redshift

Currently, one of our table size is 500 Million rows (with 35 columns), and we are trying to determine, how big can our table be before it impacts our performance on running query on that table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Performance cannot be measured like rows*columns.

It depends on the data types, joins, aggregations, etc. Your query performance can be drastically improved, for example, by creating int keys (adding columns) instead of char/varchar keys if used in joins.

Answer (score 1):

An important addition to @vtuhtan 's answer : enable compression. Create tables with compression enabled for various data types - lzo, runlength etc. Proper compression type is also suggested by Redshif on tables with `ANALYZE COMPRESSION` SQL command. This reduces the *read throughput* and drastically increases your query performance. This will also make the table consume less storage space.

[Doc on analyzing compression enabled tables](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_ANALYZE_COMPRESSION.html)

[Loading tables with compression.](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_Loading_tables_auto_compress.html)